# Multiple backend non blocking calls from NodeJS gives slow response

Tags: performance, node.js, rest

I have a specific use case which Im trying to solve using Node. The response time that I receive from NodeJS is not the one I expect.

The application is an express.js web application. The flow is as below 
a. Request reaches the server. 
b. Based on the parameter, backend REST Service is invoked. 
c. The response of the REST Service has links to multiple other objects. 
d. Navigate each of the link and agrregate the data.
e. This data is formatted (not much) and send to the client.

The actual test data- 
The response from C has got 100 links and hence I make 100 parallel calls (Im using async.map). Each of the backend service responds in less than 30 msecs. But the overall response time for 100 requests is 4 seconds. This is considerably high.

What I have observed is :
The time difference between the first backend request and the last backend request is around 3 seconds. I believe that this is due to the fact that Node is single threaded and it takes 3 seconds to place all of the 100 http requests.

The code that I use to make parallel calls is given below

```
var getIndividualRecord = function(entity,callback1)
{ 
        httpExecutor.executeRequest( entity.link.url, callback1);
}

var aggregateData = function(err, results)
{
    callback(null, results);
}
async.map(childObjects, getIndividualRecord, aggregateData);
```

The childObjects is an array with 100 records. httpExecutor makes a REST invocation using request module.

Is there something wrong Im doing or is this a wrong use case for Node?

Comment: What is `httpExecutor`? Also, are you sure you're not overloading your backend with all those requests?

Comment: httpExecutor is just a javascript function I have written. It uses request module to make the HTTP request. The backend is not overloaded, checked it.

Comment: You (probably) don't need a new queue module, async has a built in [`mapLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#maplimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) function that will let you choose a particular number of parallel things to execute, start by setting that at 10 and adjust it to see if you improve your response time

Comment: @Vaya performing 1000 requests with 100 concurrent connections (using `request`) against an Express backend on my MBP takes 0.76 seconds. My guess would be that `async` might be slowing you down if it's not the backend.

Comment: Oh, also, why aren't you using `entity` in the request, what is `link`? usually you would do something with the array item passed to the iterator function by async.map (in this case, `entity`)

Comment: @robertklep - My express app also provides good concurrency. There is no issue in the same. The issue that I have is that, Im trying to make multiple backend calls from one node instance. If you are referring to the same, can you share the sample code?

Comment: @Plato - edited the code sample. Copy paste and cleanup error!

Comment: Test code using `async.map`, `request`, and built-in Express server with simple handler: [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/2a61a8cfcdbc819ffc81). Takes about 100ms (because the Express server runs in the same process, if I run it separately it takes about 70ms). And here's another example, but you need `node-benchmark` to run it: [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/682f49c13b5ea72019cf)

Comment: @Plato : Tried using async.mapLimit but not much luck. I would think os based on what I could understand from the code of async.js

Comment: @robertklep: Tried the same program on my machine. GET / 200 15ms - 170b
GET / 200 14ms - 170b
req: 3495ms

Comment: Your assumption is that performing 100 requests with Node is slowing you down, but since I'm getting 1000+ reqs/second using the same modules you're using, I don't think it is. My guess is that the endpoint of the requests you're performing is the cause of the slowdown.

Comment: @robertklep: I used the exact same program that you gisted. Looks like , the speed of my processor is much lower than yours. The timing that I have provided in the previous comment is for the program you provided

Comment: Ah okay sorry about that! Try lowering the number of requests to about 50 and see what the timing is then.

Comment: @robertklep : Just halved. One more thing I noticed was , if I use the exact function: app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(200);
}); - then I get 200 msecs. If I change this to app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("data");
    res.send(200);
}); - then the time is 3000 msecs, only additon is res.render.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a very slow templating engine (or you're rendering a lot of data)

Answer (score 0):

You're assumption is correct: node is single threaded, so while your HTTP requests happen in a *nonblocking* manner (requests are made right after the other without even waiting for the response from the server), they don't truly happen in *simultaneously*.

So, yes, it's probable it takes Node 3 seconds to get through all these requests and process them.

There are a few ways "around" this, which might work depending on your situation:

1. Could you use Node's `cluster` module to spawn multiple node apps and each do a portion of the work? Then you *would* be doing things simultaneously (since you have N Node processes going on).
2. Use a background queue mechanism (aka: Resque, Beanstalk) and have a background worker (or a process spawned with Cluster) to distribute the work (to Node worker processes waiting around to pick things off this queue)
3. Refactor your web app a little bit to deal with the fact that parts will take a while. Perhaps render most of the page then onload make an ajax request that fires off the 3 second route and then puts the results in some DOM element when the AJAX request comes back.

Comment: I tried using Redis. It gives me similar numbers. Again, the time taken to publish the message to the queue is considered. Regd the cluster, I have clustered the app but the work doesnt get shared between 2 clusters , since the main request is handled by just one cluster. Regd option 3 - I agree that there are ways to handle the web app and the user experience.

Comment: Well, can you provide more details (with sample pseudo code ) for option 2 mentioned. I have the publish subscribe code but not sure about the background worker process

Answer (score 0):

i have similar scenario and similar observation.

in my case I run node app using pm2. in app there are 2 sub servers (let's call them A and B). pm2 spawns 2 processes per each server. from a client i call server A, it calculates simple thing and call server B in async manner. when server B responds server A sends data back to client.

very simple scenario but when I used jmeter to create 1000 threads (where each thread makes 50 calls)to call server A I got average response around 4 sec (for 50000 calls).

server B responds after 50ms and I think this is the problem. during first 50ms nodejs processes lots of incoming requests and then it cannot quickly process responses from server B and incoming calls.

I would expect that application code is executed in single thread but there supposed to be background threads to deal with all the rest. it seems this is not the case.